# How can zsh be configured to autocomplete directory name with camelcase matching?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, filenames

Eclipse and Resharper have a nice way of navigating files.

If I have the following folders (or files) in my current directory

```
MyReallyLongName
MyReallyLongAndFunName
MyReallyLongAndNotReallyFunName
```

In eclipse I can navigate to them by using only the capitalized letters. Correspondingly in zsh I want to be able to type:

> cd MRLAFN(Tab)(Enter)

To get into `MyReallyLongAndFunName` in one step

If I want to do that with zsh right now, I have to type `My(Tab)Fun(Tab)(Enter)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:[^A-Z0-9]||[A-Z0-9]=** r:|=*'
```

Then I can do this in a test directory:

```
touch MyReallyLongName MyReallyLongAndFunName MyReallyLongAndNotReallyFunName
ls MRLANRFN<TAB>
ls MyReallyLongAndNotReallyFunName
```

I cobbled it together from tips in the [Zshell User's Guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html#l175).

Comment: Can you please describe where I have to place this extension (file, folder)? You might also be interested in adding it to the [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions) project.

Comment: add it to your ~/.zshrc

Comment: This doesn't quite work as expected, with `AbcAde AdFg HlAkAd`, `ls AA<TAB>` completes to `Ad`, while I'd expect AbcAde.

Comment: @arekolek "Ad" is a partial completion. If you hit TAB again (depending on your zsh configuration) you will see all the files that match.  It should include all three files. Then you can choose one with the menu selection or by typing some more of the filename to guide the completer.

Comment: @arekolek Sorry - I read that wrong.  I'm not sure how you got to Ad from there. I thought it was a partial-ambiguous match, but it's hard to tell from your example.  Does a 2nd TAB produce any more results?

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work "quite well" by adding a file `_camel_case` to my personal `~/.zsh/functions folder` (take any folder that is in your `$fpath` variable) with the following content:

```
#autoload

[[ -z "$PREFIX" ]] && return 1

relpath=$(dirname $PREFIX)

[[ -e $relpath ]] || return 1

files=$(ls $relpath)

regex=$(echo $(basename $PREFIX) | sed -e 's/\([A-Z][^A-Z]*\)/\1[^A-Z]+/g')

correctedfiles=($(echo $files | grep -P $regex | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/ /;ta'))

results=($(for file in $correctedfiles; do echo "$relpath/$file"; done))

compadd -U -f -- $results
```

Then, I added the following line to my ~/.zshrc

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _correct _path_files _camel_case
```

Note that this is most probably not a "good" solution as I do not have too much knowledge of the completion system of zsh (only few people really have, I guess), but it does exactly what you described in your question.

Comment: This only somewhat works..
 mkdir AaBbCcDd
 cd ABCD (tab) => cd ./ 
 ie. Autocomplete fails