# How to autocomplete filenames with "wordwise" camelcase matching in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

While programming using QtCreator, I got used to its camelcase-aware completion, e.g. typing `MC<ctrl-space>` would offer `MyClass` as a completion option.

Now I am basically annoyed about that because I sometimes type `MD<tab>` in bash and expect it to offer `MyDirectory` as a completion option, if that directory exists. Can bash be configured to actually do that?

Note that this question is basically the same as this one, but about bash instead of zsh:
[How can zsh be configured to autocomplete directory name with camelcase matching?](https://superuser.com/questions/394824/how-can-zsh-be-configured-to-autocomplete-directory-name-with-camelcase-matching)

Comment: Would this question be better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your .inputrc

> set completion-ignore-case On

That should turn on case-insensitive autocompletion... which will then work for camelcased files.

Comment: Ah... I see now that you only want to type the uppercase letters... that won't work with this setting, but you should still be able to match files/dirs with the first letters correct in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: Right, I would only want to type `ED` for the completion to `ExampleDirectory`, with your answer I would have to type e.g. `ex<tab>`.